# 2 decimal places missing in price(PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, dreamweaver, number-formatting, decimal-point

I have a problem with 2 decimal places, I want it to be USD 35.99 instead of USD 3599.

This problem occurred when I kept refreshing my page for testing purposes. Sometimes the price shows no decimal places, but gets back to normal after I keep testing my page.

Does anyone knows why is it so?
Below is my php code:

```
// format for currency values
function cartweaverMoney($theNum) {
    $cwLocaleInfo = localeconv();
    $cwLocaleInfo["currency_symbol"] = 'USD ';
    $retStr = number_format($theNum, 
                    2, 
                    $cwLocaleInfo["mon_decimal_point"],
                    $cwLocaleInfo["mon_thousands_sep"]);
    if ($cwLocaleInfo["p_cs_precedes"]) {
        if ($cwLocaleInfo["p_sep_by_space"]) {
            $retStr = " ".$retStr;
        }
        $retStr = $cwLocaleInfo["currency_symbol"].$retStr;
    } else {
        if ($cwLocaleInfo["p_sep_by_space"]) {
            $retStr .= " ";
        }
        $retStr .= $cwLocaleInfo["currency_symbol"];
    }
    return $retStr; 
}
```

Comment: you should definitely check whats in these two variables $cwLocaleInfo["mon_decimal_point"],
                    $cwLocaleInfo["mon_thousands_sep"]  to make sure you have valid seperaters, etc

Comment: I suppose you are referring to this code? I'm not familiart with php, but I found this code withing the same php page with header // LOCALE SETTINGS for js currency format

Comment: $_ENV["application.cw"]["currencyPrecedes"] = false;
  $_ENV["application.cw"]["currencySymbol"] = "";
  $_ENV["application.cw"]["currencyDecimal"] = ".";
  $_ENV["application.cw"]["currencyGroup"] = ",";
  $_ENV["application.cw"]["currencySpace"] = "";

Answer (score 0):

Before localeconv() you have to use 'setlocale':

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US");
$locale_info = localeconv();
```

http://php.net/manual/it/function.localeconv.php

or, maybe, check this code:
http://php.net/manual/it/function.number-format.php

```
<?php
$var = number_format(2234,2);
$var = number_format($var,2);
echo $var;
# Expected Output: 2,234.00
# Actual Output: 2.00
?>

//To fix, remove the thousands separator by setting the decimal point and thousands separator parameters like so:

<?php
$var = number_format(2234,2,'.','');
$var = number_format($var,2,'.','');
echo $var;
# Expected Output: 2234.00
# Actual Output: 2234.00
?>
```

Enjoy your code!

Edited:
I have made in Windows system to print the localconv() array return, it's void.
setloca

```
le(LC_ALL, "en_US");
$cwLocaleInfo = localeconv();
function print_locale_conv($locale_info) {
    echo "<pre>\n";
    echo "--------------------------------------------\n";
    echo "  Informazioni sulla configurazione monetaria locale:  \n";
    echo "--------------------------------------------\n\n";

    echo "int_curr_symbol:   {$locale_info["int_curr_symbol"]}\n";
    echo "currency_symbol:   {$locale_info["currency_symbol"]}\n";
    echo "mon_decimal_point: {$locale_info["mon_decimal_point"]}\n";
    echo "mon_thousands_sep: {$locale_info["mon_thousands_sep"]}\n";
    echo "positive_sign:     {$locale_info["positive_sign"]}\n";
    echo "negative_sign:     {$locale_info["negative_sign"]}\n";
    echo "int_frac_digits:   {$locale_info["int_frac_digits"]}\n";
    echo "frac_digits:       {$locale_info["frac_digits"]}\n";
    echo "p_cs_precedes:     {$locale_info["p_cs_precedes"]}\n";
    echo "p_sep_by_space:    {$locale_info["p_sep_by_space"]}\n";
    echo "n_cs_precedes:     {$locale_info["n_cs_precedes"]}\n";
    echo "n_sep_by_space:    {$locale_info["n_sep_by_space"]}\n";
    echo "p_sign_posn:       {$locale_info["p_sign_posn"]}\n";
    echo "n_sign_posn:       {$locale_info["n_sign_posn"]}\n";
    echo "</pre>\n";
}
?>
```

So I have read this:
http://php.net/manual/it/function.setlocale.php

and I have change the parameter for localeconv():

```
$lang = "us_US";
$language = 'english';
$codeset = "UTF8";  // warning ! not UTF-8 with dash '-'

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Rome');
setlocale(LC_ALL, array($lang.'.'.$codeset,$lang.'@euro',$lang,$language));

$cwLocaleInfo = localeconv();

print_locale_conv($cwLocaleInfo);
```

Whit these works!

For *nix system try to use this:

```
$lang = "us_US";
$language = 'english';
$codeset = "UTF8";  // warning ! not UTF-8 with dash '-'
putenv('LANG='.$lang.'.'.$codeset);
putenv('LANGUAGE='.$lang.'.'.$codeset);
```

Comment: I tried to add this >> _italic setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US") << before >> $cwLocaleInfo = localeconv(); << ;but it doesn't changed anything. And, when I changed   $retStr = number_format($theNum, 
                    2, 
                    $cwLocaleInfo["mon_decimal_point"],
                    $cwLocaleInfo["mon_thousands_sep"]);

to   $retStr = number_format($theNum, 2, '.','');    the thousand seperator is disappear. Any idea?

Comment: thanks for your prompt reply Magicianred, I will try it later. : )